# Grafana Status History with Multiple Metrics

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to use Grafana's [status history](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/status-history/) visualization to show the working status of different wallets.

I have counter `withdrawals_requests_total{currency=$currency}`, which gets incremented once there's a new request. And I have another counter `withdrawal_wallets_total{currency=$currency, id=$id}`, which increments after a successful withdrawal via the specific wallet ID. A wallet may have multiple currencies.

My goal is to have a status history graph with `{{currency}}-{{wallet ID}}` as row titles. And at a specific time, the status should be:

- WARN: `increase(withdrawal_wallets_total{currency, id})` =
  0 or missing AND `increase(withdrawals_requests_total{currency})` > 0
- OK: Otherwise

So the graph should give warning if there're withdrawal requests of a certain currency but a wallet which supports that currency is never used for a period of time.

There's another gauge metric `wallet_balance_total{currency, id}` whose value is the current wallet balance of a currency. It's updated at a fixed interval and it's a complete list of wallets. I guess I might need it to list all the wallets in the graph.

I'd like to know how can I configure the Grafana panel in order to have such a graph?

Comment: So, for every pair (currency, id) in wallet_balance_total there should be a row, with either OK or WARN based on rule provided?

Comment: @markalex Yes, that's the goal

Comment: I've looked at some examples here: https://play.grafana.org/d/qD-rVv6Mz/6-state-timeline-and-status-history?orgId=1 and it seems to be impossible to do it with status history. There's not a way to dynamically construct the queries.  Each row in status history is a separate time series. Not sure if there're workarounds with table panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need, you can use following query:

```bash
wallet_balance_total{} * 0 +
on(currency) group_left() (
  (
    increase(withdrawals_requests_total{}[1h]) > 0 #If needed here can be applied *0+1
    unless on(currency) increase(withdrawal_wallets_total{}[1h])>0
  )
  or sum by(currency)(wallet_balance_total)*0
)
```

Here:

- `wallet_balance_total` is used to get all the label pairs (currency, id). `*0` is used to ignore value of the metric,
- `+ on(currency) group_left()` adding results of RHS, pairing based on `currency` label and preserving other labels of LHS,

  - expression that returns result only if condition you described in question is met,
  - `or sum by(currency)(wallet_balance_total)*0` if previous condition didn't return anything - return 0 with attached labels (hack for promql instead of "left join")

This query will return result equal to increase of `withdrawals_requests_total`. If you'd prefer 0 or 1, wrap expression before comment into brackets and apply mentioned `*0+1` trick.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, just saw your answer.  I tested it and it worked! I'm still trying to understand it though.

Answer (score 1):

After days of explorations, it seems impossible to do so purely on Grafana. I'm thinking about doing the logic in the application and then post the results (status being OK or WARN) as a new Gauge metric.

I can probably setup a cron job to loop through all the dynamically retrieved currency-wallet pairs. And in each loop, query the Prometheus API to run some PromQLs, get the results, and then apply the rule.  If it's a WARN, set the gauge to -1 with the corresponding currency and wallet ID labels. Else set it to 1.

Then in grafana I can setup a table panel for the gauge, set the threshold and give different colors to visualize the results.

Not a perfect solution, but I guess it's the only way.